# Adding Oracle Spatial View as Layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, oracle-spatial, spatial-view

Is it possible to add an Oracle Spatial View on QGIS MAP?

My view is registered on MDSYS metadata but, when I connect with Oracle DB, it is disabled on the list.

```
QGIS Desktop 2.2.0

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.4.0      Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have not defined a SRID in the **user_sdo_geom_metadata** view? If not you can define the SRID in QGIS. When you get the list of layers, click on the SRID column for your view and then enter the desired SRID. The layer name should get enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to select the primary key, sometimes this isn't set on views